# Code to fill matrix with 'yes' or 'no' based on input

Tags: vba, excel

I have a matrix in an Excel sheet. In the first column are names of computers and in the other rows, I have users who are using it. For each computer there could be one associated user or two users and so on.

I wish to create a matrix of computers in the column and the all the users in the row and have VBA code to search the sheet, and if the user uses that computer, the output should be `yes`, else `no`.

Main Sheet

```
Computer A   Dev     Priya   Rakesh  Joseph     
Computer B   Rakesh  Joseph             
Computer C   John    Nisha   Dev
```

Output Sheet

```
Computers     Dev   Priya   Rakesh  Joseph  John    Nisha

Computer A     Y     Y       Y        Y      N       N  
Computer B     N     N       Y        Y      N       N  
Computer C     Y     N       N        N      Y       Y
```

Comment: Please explain your situation clearly. Are the users working on networked terminals. How the user use of computer event is planned to be transferred to the Main Sheet recording use of computers. What approach you have tried so far to work it out. Where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rename sheet to 'Main' and copy data to it start from range A1.
Beware blank cell because I check end of row and column by check cell is "".
Rename other sheet to 'Output'.
Copy my code then run.
Note: Output sheet will clear all the time you run this macro.

```
Sub createMatrix()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim rngFind As Range

' Clear all contents in sheets output
Sheets("Output").Activate
Sheets("Output").Cells.ClearContents

i = 0
j = 1
k = 1
Do While Sheets("Main").Range("A1").Offset(i).Value <> ""
    ' Insert computer name to output sheet
    Sheets("Output").Range("A2").Offset(i).Value = Sheets("Main").Range("A1").Offset(i).Value

    Do While Sheets("Main").Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value <> ""
        ' Check name is exists?
        Set rngFind = Rows("1:1").Find(what:=Sheets("Main").Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If rngFind Is Nothing Then
            ' If not exists paste new name
            Sheets("Output").Range("A1").Offset(0, k).Value = Sheets("Main").Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value

            ' Mark use as 'Y'
            Sheets("Output").Range("A1").Offset(i + 1, k).Value = "Y"
            k = k + 1
        Else
            ' Mark use as 'Y'
            rngFind.Offset(i + 1).Value = "Y"
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
    j = 1
Loop

' This loop for Mark 'N'
i = 0
j = 1
Do While Sheets("Output").Range("A2").Offset(i).Value <> ""
    Do While Sheets("Output").Range("A1").Offset(0, j).Value <> ""
        ' If found blank cell Mark 'N'
        If Sheets("Output").Range("A2").Offset(i, j).Value = "" Then
            Sheets("Output").Range("A2").Offset(i, j).Value = "N"
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
    j = 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Sample main sheet and output
[image: main sheet]

[image: outputsheet]

Answer (score 0):

This version creates a new sheet

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TheMatrixReloaded()  'There is no spoon
   Const FR As Long = 1:   Const FC As Long = 2
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, ur As Range
   Dim ud As Object, cel As Range, i As Long
   Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   With ws1.UsedRange
     lr = ws1.Cells(.Rows.Count + .Row + 1, FC - 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Set ur = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(FR + 1, FC), ws1.Cells(lr, .Columns.Count + .Column - 1))
   End With
   Set ud = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ws1)
   ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(FR, FC - 1), ws1.Cells(lr, FC - 1)).Copy ws2.Cells(FR, FC - 1)
   For Each cel In ur
      With cel
         If Len(.Value2) > 0 Then
            If Not ud.Exists(.Value2) Then
               ud.Add .Value2, FC + i
               ws2.Cells(FR, FC + i).Value2 = .Value2
               ws2.Cells(.Row, FC + i).Value2 = "Y":  i = i + 1
            Else
               ws2.Cells(.Row, ud(.Value2)).Value2 = "Y"
            End If
         End If
      End With
   Next
   With ws2.UsedRange
      Set ur = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(FR + 1, FC), ws2.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
      Set ur = ur.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
   End With
   ur.Value2 = "N": ur.Font.Color = RGB(177, 177, 177)
   ws2.Columns(1).AutoFit: ws2.UsedRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   ws2.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

[image: before]

---

[image: after]